# long long int in windowsxp and windows7

Tags: c

I have a program and inside it I put Q=pow(2.0,32)
When I run this program in a computer that has a 32- bit system of windows7 it will work
but when I copy it to a computer that has  a 64-bit system windowsxp it will give me Q=0
what is the problem?
Q is long long int

Comment: Did you **recompile it** for the 64 bit system?

Comment: Windows XP 64-bit is *extremely* unusual. Are you sure that's what you have?

Comment: Professional x64 Edition From system summary system type is x64-base PC

Comment: I am trying to printf("x=%lld",LONG_LONG_MAX); in the first computer it will give me correct answer but in the second one (windows xp) it give me zero

Comment: `pow()` returns a result of type `double`. `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. Unless your program is compiled or linked inconsistently, that should work -- though the result could conceivably be inexact. Do you have `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: You could also try printing what `sizeof(long long int)` gives on each system, if You think there problem is because of possibly different sizes. * shrug *

Comment: *"I am trying to printf("x=%lld",LONG_LONG_MAX);"* -- That's completely different from what you said in your question. But it's possible that Microsoft's runtime library doesn't properly support the `"%lld"` format. Microsoft's support for C99 and later is very poor, and C99 introduced the `long long` type.

Comment: Please show us (in your question) the source for a small compile version of your program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I just write the one command and run it on the first computer then copy the program as is and run it on the second computer

Comment: I think the problem in windows type or computer speed

Comment: I seriously doubt that computer speed has anything at all to do with it. See my answer, and try the things I suggested.

Comment: To get 2^32 use (1ULL << 32), **do not** use power functions. To get 2^n with n < 32 use (1 << n)

Answer (score 1):

How do you *know* that `Q` is 0?

If you're printing it using something like `printf("%lld\n", Q);`, it's likely you're running into a deficiency in Microsoft's C runtime library.  Microsoft's support for C99 is minimal, and it's likely they don't support the `"%lld"` format (I'm surprised their compiler permits `long long int`).

Try *comparing* `Q` to 0 in addition to printing the value of `Q`:

```
printf("Q = %lld\n", Q);
if (Q == 0) {
    puts("Q == 0");
}
else {
    puts("Q != 0");
}
```

And consult Microsoft's documentation for their supported way to print a `long long int` value.

Comment: I write printf("max=%lld",LONG_LONG_MAX);
in the first windows7 computer it will print 923.... and when I compile the same program in windowsxp it will give me -1, and when I try it in my laptop windows7 it print 923....,so I thing the problem in windows type

Comment: @MousaFarajallah: Are you asking about the `pow()` function, or are you asking about `LONG_LONG_MAX`? Your question doesn't mention `LONG_LONG_MAX`; if you want to ask about that, please update your question. Either way, please update your question to show us a *complete* *compilable* program (including the `main()` function and any required `#include` directives) that illustrates the problem you're having. It shouldn't need to be more than half a dozen lines or so. Without that, you're forcing us to guess what you're really doing. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I use Q=pow(2.0,32) as Q is LONG LONG int, then when I print it it give me correct answer in first PC and -1 in the other PC, to check the max value of LONG LONG int I use the printf("max=%lld",LONG_LONG_MAX); and the answer is the same correct answer for the first PC and -1 for the second PC, I will put the code tomorrow when I go to the lab

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include "highgui.h"
    int main()
    {
    long long int Q;
    Q=pow(2.0,32);
    printf("%lld\n",Q);
    printf("%lld\n",LONG_LONG_MAX); return 0; 
    }
```